# sql server: select values from two different tables

Tags: sql-server, select

I have two tables PublicSettings and PrivateSettings. PublicSettings has all the default settings for different types of users while PrivateSettings keeps only a user specific setting which its value is different from default settings. I want to read all settings for a user but if the setting exists in private one get the value from this table and if not from the public one.

```
select settingname, value from PublicSettings where usertype=@type
```

this select all default settings but for example imagine that the setting "show_captcha_on_login" is disabled by default but same settingname is true for a single user in private settings, I want to get all from public but this one (that exists in private settings) from the private settings.

by the way PrivateSetting has the same column names except it has a user_id column too, for selecting user specific settings

Comment: Select coalesce( t2.a, t1.a ) from defaults t1 left outer join privates t2 on ...

Comment: coalesce works if the value is null in the privatesettings table and selects from the other one, the thing is that the record doesn't exist in privatesettings unless it has a different value than public settings

Comment: That's why you'd use an *outer* join between the tables...

Comment: imagine that a specific user type has 5 default settings but in private settings there are only 2 settings iwth same column name but with different values I want to select these 2 from private settings and other 3 from public settings

Comment: could you please write the code?

Comment: Could you have a look at my first comment instead?

Comment: @HannoBinder I tested your code column names are as I want but values are not: `select  o.name,coalesce(s.value,o.value) from publicsettings as o left outer join privatesettings as s on o.utype =s.utype where s.[uid] =1`

Comment: Looks ok to me. However, I don't know your data model/table structure and so cannot tell if there still is a mistake in the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 SELECT  
    pub.name, 
    CASE WHEN (pub.name = priv.name ) THEN priv.value ELSE pub.value END AS value
FROM 
    PublicSettings pub 
    LEFT JOIN PrivateSettings priv ON (pub.utype = priv.utype)
WHERE 
    priv.[uid]=1
```

Comment: your code had some problems but the Idea was correct I just edited your answer, thanks

Comment: Great! I have accepted the changes, please review the 'left join' to bring all data from PublicSettings that are not in PrivateSettings

Answer (score 1):

You must make use of an outer join because the user-specific value only exists for some of the public values. The non-appearance of a private value will return a NULL, which you can use to determine which value to return.

```
SELECT pub.settingname, 
       ISNULL(priv.value,pub.value) AS value
  FROM PublicSettings  pub 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PrivateSettings priv 
    ON pub.settingname = priv.settingname
   AND priv.userid = @userid
 WHERE pub.usertype=@type;
```

Comment: I don't know but I tested the code and it worked perfectly with left jion

Comment: Yes, the OUTER key word is optional, so LEFT JOIN is equivalent to LEFT OUTER JOIN.